# What is the Haskell `(->) a` monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

At the page http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree#Tool_support, it talks about the `(->) a` monad.

What is this monad? The use of symbols makes it hard to google.

Comment: You'd call it _function monad_ in words, or _reader monad_ (though that typically refers to [the explicitly named equivalent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html)).

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#the-monad-type-class

Answer (score 4):

This is a Reader monad.  You can think of it as

```
type Reader r = (->) r -- Reader r a == (->) r a == r -> a
instance Monad (Reader r) where
  return a = const a            
  m >>= f = \r -> f (m r) r
```

And do computations like:

```
double :: Num r => Reader r r
double = do
  v <- id
  return (2*v)
```

Comment: Use Case: You can use this to supply code with a configuration file. Or in some type checkers, keep track of the environment

Answer (score 4):

It is the function monad, and it's a bit weird to understand.  It's also sometimes called the Reader monad, by the way.  I think the best way to illustrate how it works is through an example:

```hs
f1 :: Double -> Double
f1 x = 10 * x + x ** 2 + 3 * x ** 3

f2 :: Double -> Double
f2 = do
    x1 <- (10 *)
    x2 <- (** 2)
    x3 <- (** 3)
    return $ x1 + x2 + 3 * x3
```

If you try out both of these, you'll see that you get the same output from both.  So what exactly is going on?  When you "extract" a value from a function, you get what can be considered its "return value".  I put quotes around it because when you `return` a value from this monad, the value you return is a function.

For an example like this, the implicit argument to `f2` gets passed to each `<-` as an implicit argument.  It can be fairly useful if you have a lot of sub expressions with the same argument.  As the Reader monad, it is generally used to supply read-only config values.